# iOS Simulator Doesn't Install Application

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, xcode5, ios-simulator

Using Xcode 5.1 to debug an iOS 7.1 iPad application.

When I build and run my project in the iOS Simulator, the simulator opens and my app icon pops up for a second. Then it looks like the app stops installing and the simulator goes to the home screen. Xcode still thinks it's debugging and it doesn't show any errors in Xcode or the simulator. I can go to my app in the simulator and click it again, but it just crashes. I get the same behavior in iPad, iPad Retina, and iPad Retina (64 bit). Any subsequent tries to run the app in the simulator doesn't even attempt to pop the app icon up until I quit the iOS Simulator and try again. All the usual fixes haven't worked for me yet.

Fixes I've Tried:
1. iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...
2. Window(in Xcode) > Organizer > Delete Derived Data & Delete Snapshots
3. Delete Contents in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator
4. Uninstall Xcode and reinstall
5. Clean project and rebuild
6. Restart machine

I'm out of ideas. Is there something I've missed?

Thanks all!

Comment: If you try making a new project from a template, do you have the same issue, or is it specific to this App? Is anything being printed to the console?

Comment: Nothing is being printed to the console. When I make a new project from a template it runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the problem. I was playing with how we load our frameworks because we were having other issues before and I left a bad value in our Linking settings.

Here's how I fixed it:
Project > Build Settings > Linking > Mach-O Type set to "Executable"

It was set to "Bundles" before which causes Xcode to package the app in a way that caused ours to break.

Helpful Post: [In Xcode project target build settings, What is Mach-O Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082149/in-xcode-project-target-build-settings-what-is-mach-o-type)

Answer (score 0):

Create another app with the exact same template and look at the app delegates and make sure they are the same.

Example: AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m

You might've accidentally deleted an area that helps load the App.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I did that too. New projects run perfectly fine in the simulator.